# 2021th derivative at x=0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

It was from my school's calculus competition(already end):
$$
\left.(\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2})^{(2021)}\right \vert_{x=0}
$$[image]

it's the contest time. translate:
"Competition time: May 25, 2021 (Tuesday) 15:50-17:40 pm"(GMT+8)

Comment: And can we get a proof that the competition has ended?

Comment: How about the fact that OP's posting here?

Comment: OP, what did you try?

Comment: From any running contest  ?

Comment: I edited the question, sorry for not having proof before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can expand as a power series centered at zero
$$
f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1+x+x^2}=\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^3}=\sum_0^\infty(x^{3n}-x^{3n+2}).
$$
Therefore, since $2021$ is of the form $3n+2$, the coefficient of $x^{2021}$ in the series is $-1$. That means that
$$
-1=f^{(2021)}(0)/2021!
$$
and therefore $f^{(2021)}(0)=-2021!$

Comment: I would encourage you to please verify the contest has ended before posting an answer.

Comment: @K.defaoite I understand your point, but I can't think of any reliable way to do that.